# English parts of speech — better new treatments

Tags: parts-of-speech, resources

Can anyone please recommend a better treatment of English parts of speech / word classes than that offered by most traditional grammars?

Many of the latter stick with the sacrosanct 8 of antiquity, or perhaps allow for one or two more, while POS Tagsets may contain many hundreds of tags (catering for subsets such as plural nouns, verb forms etc). Demanding that we stick with eight for sentimental reasons seems like saying 'Let's just have four (chemical) elements, like they used to do, because that's easier.' Some parts of speech — 'function words' — are distinguished according to function — or called adverbs if they show a vague resemblance in some respect and we don't like having more than 8 (or 12 or 24) classes. However, having 750 classes as a working model does seem to be erring the other way.

Does anyone *please* know of a sensible (Goldilocks!) treatment?

Comment: It depends on the context. It seems reasonable to introduce children to the notion that the words of a language have different functions, and to use the traditional parts of speech to designate those functions. Older children can be taught that the boundaries between the word classes are not always clear-cut. And linguists will need a much more sophisticated set of terms to describe the language under analysis.

Comment: +1 for the comparison with the 4 classical elements, love it!

Comment: I'm surprised you don't mention phlogiston. As Shoe says, it depends on the context. However, I don't agree that dumbing it down is the right way to explain it to kids -- why not just tell them the truth? They can handle it. The basics of language are simple - there are words and they break into consonants and vowels, and there are sentences and they break into constituents make out of words. Kids love breaking things apart and putting them back to gether, especially when accompanied by funny noises (I'm working on an answer, but I won't be able to put it up for a while.)

Comment: It is useful for teachers and students to share a metalanguage to discuss what the students are given to read and write; and for students to understand differences between languages. If we don't use the traditional terms, then we are reduced to saying things like: "*Your describing words lack pep*"; "*Every sentence needs a doing word*"; "*In German, words denoting how things are done do not have a different form from their corresponding describing words, as they do in English.*" I would settle for all students leaving school at the least being able to name each of the traditional POS.

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer, I have a few questions. (1) Would you prefer a classification that is motivated mostly by semantics, syntax, or a compromise? (2) Any idea how many classes you want (30, 100, 300)? (3) Would you prefer an English-centric scheme or one valid across languages? (4) Would you accept or reject classes that have no overt members and are only posited to make a theory work?

Comment: @Rachel Sorry; I've not seen a prompt till now! (1) compromise (risky, I know, but the others don't work). (2) I've managed to keep below 40 by lumping 'pragmatic markers' (which includes M-W lexemes) into 1 and having subclasses. (3) English only, for my purposes. (4) I'm trying to see how English works. For example, I've got a new class for (hitherto-labelled) non-semantically predicative adjectives, such as 'mere'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Edwin, I want to ask you for your forgiveness for making that terrible comment about you in chat. I couldn't understand (pride, I guess; but more than that, too) why you would discourage me from posting. I was hurt. Please forgive me.

Comment: The Boss demands I do. I'm not trying to discourage you from posting, and certainly not trying to discourage you per se. The vast majority of your posts are (I'm British) accurate, pertinent, and have interesting and well-researched details. In this case, after the previous misleading answer of someone's ('this is an adverb because it describes the manner of an action; _that is a preposition because it describes place_' or similar) I felt I had to step in quite strongly. :-) PS I'm up to about 30 parts of speech.

Comment: I think your question is POB. May I vote to close it as POB?

Comment: Of course you can. I possibly wouldn't ask this question here nowadays; it's a request for resources. Though I'm still looking for a better treatment. BUT you're obviously reacting in a personal manner to a close-vote I correctly made in another question, and that rapidly becomes flaggable behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at one of the better modern descriptions of English grammar. The best of course is the ["Cambridge Grammar of the English Language"](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/) by Pullum and Huddlestone. This has an excellent analysis of English POS but is very expensive so an alternative is ["A Student's Introduction to English Grammar"](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/A_Student_s_Introduction_To_English_Gram.html?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&redir_esc=y), written by the same authors and based on the larger work, but briefer and cheaper.

Comment: After quite a lot of thought, we at Wordwizard have had to relegate the CGEL to 'useful but dated', as P & H's work did to Quirk et al, Gaston. Sadly, we recognise that although P & H did a fine job of presenting a better if imperfect alternative, we haven't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying there's a better description of English parts of speech than that in CGEL? Also, I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: I was responding to your overall claim about CGEL's pre-eminence, Gaston. With regard to treatments of parts of speech, I've found monographs, treatments of individual areas (**eg 1** 'adjectives'[?]-not-modifying-closest-nouns-or-indeed-any-obvious-noun: _mere_ is an example; **eg 2** pragmatic markers). My second sentence is in recognition of the fine work in CGEL - better than I could come up with. But imperfect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, but I'm still curious that you would call CGEL 'dated', and wonder what has superceded it? As for POS being better analyed in more recent monographs, yes fair enough, books never keep up with articles.

Comment: My initial question was, to a fair approximation, the one you have just put.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, I thought that in saying CGEL is 'useful but date' you were suggesting that something has superceded it. It was published in 2002 so it's very recent and hardly to be described as 'dated' unless something better has come along.

Comment: English Grammar: A University Course by Downing & Locke; 2nd ed 2006 is worth investigating - I can only access internet excerpts for most of the grammars. Grammar: A Student's Guide - James R. Hurford (1994) is also good, at least the parts I've accessed.               There is a distinct difference in meaning between _dated_ and _not published in the last few years_, Gaston, and it is often the approach to analysis in CGEL one or two of us find unhelpful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your mention of Downing & Locke brings up the question of whether you're after a pedagogical style treatment (such as the D&L), or a truly descriptively adequate treatment (such as CGEL).

Comment: I'm sorry, Gaston. I can't agree that CGEL offer/s 'a truly descriptively adequate [/accurate] treatment'. To give just one major shortcoming: in an article at http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/cappelle/Pdf%20versions%20of%20papers/The%20particularity%20of%20particles.pdf, Bert Cappelle gives three sound analytical reasons why 'locative and directional particles' (such as _here_, _home_ in He is here, He went home) cannot reasonably be classified as ('intransitive') prepositions - which Huddleston and Pullum, following other grammarians, do in CGEL.        E Ashworth

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough: but it's the *most* descriptively adequate treatment of English grammar. Of course it will be improved upon, particularly by articles that focus on some specific aspect of English. But as a description of English grammar, there's currently no better.

Comment: That was the answer I was expecting, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Which set of categories is "just right" depends on your purpose and the type of analysis that you want to perform. (Though yes, it's clear that the traditional set of 8-10 categories is inadequate for pretty much any purpose...)

I would suggest that you start with the tagset for one of the major corpora and group together categories that you don't need to differentiate for your purposes.