# Can an adverb be a noun?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, comparisons, construction

I have seen [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111426/can-an-adverb-be-a-noun-at-the-same-time) for the answer to my question, but this is not much help in case of the question I am going to ask.

Here is an example sentence -

> The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile **than** never **before**.

***than*** here is a preposition, there is no doubt about that. But ***before*** after ***than*** acts like a noun. But from dictionary entry against ***before*** doesn't say it's a noun.

So what is the explanation?

Comment: Not an answer, but I am wondering about your use of _never_. I would personally say "more than _ever_ before_". Or actually "more than ever".

Comment: @oerkelens Or if you omit "never", and place "ever" in place of "never"?

Comment: @oerkelens Actually I have omitted some part of the sentence considering it as ellipses. The sentence I wrote originally is **The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile that (it has been) never before***

Comment: Isn't that the same as using ever instead of never, like I did?

Comment: In the longer version as well, I would use ever instead of never. But I am not sure it's relevant :)

Comment: Could you explain what makes you think it is a noun? _He's running faster than he **was**_, _He's running faster than **before**_. Would you call either _was_ or _before_ in these examples nouns?

Comment: In case of **He was running faster than he was**, after preposition ***than***, a noun clause - ***he was*** - is placed. And in your second sentence the issue you address, matches exactly with the issue I asked in my original question. In my original sentence I didn't try to mean "before" is a noun, I am always saying it's an adverb, but after a preposition a noun should be placed.

Comment: Oh really? But why? And when? By whom? For what?

Comment: I really didn't get why what? and when what? Are you asking why I made this statement - after a preposition a noun should be placed?

Comment: @terdon I think I was not clear to you when I asked this question. Sorry for that. It's because of my inability to clearly say what exactly my confusion is.

Comment: Exactly. Those were various examples of prepositions that are not followed by nouns. There is no such thing as a "after a preposition a noun should be placed" rule. In fact, this is _English_ there aren't really any rules at all. Just polite suggestions. In any case, I see no reason why a preposition should or even tends to be followed by a noun.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your inputs. Exactly. It's true that a language doesn't follow a certain rules. But the non native speakers wants a simple formula ;) or else you know what happens. Nothing makes sense to them :D Thanks again. I will be careful.

Comment: Add *"than never before"* to the [eggcorn database](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/).

Comment: @Man_From_India: when people look for simple rules, they may think it makes learning a language easier. In reality, it makes it very confusing and more difficult because at some point they have to _unlearn_ all those "rules".

Comment: No an adverb can never be a noun.  A word might play the role of an adverb at one time or a noun at another time, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> '[T]han here is a preposition, there is no doubt about that.' [OP]

and

> 'A noun is the only part of speech possible after a preposition'

and

> In the accepted phrase 'better than ever before', 'ever' cannot be a noun.

So we have a contradiction. The only question to address really is **how many** of the above assertions are not true?

If we look at

> 'It is better than [it] ever [was before]

we find a construction which presents no problems. Here, 'than' is a conjunction; there is no doubt about that. 'Ever' is an adverb.

But in the ellipted version, 'than' is now an ex-conjunction and 'ever' is an ex-adverb. In other words, forcing traditional analyses on elliptical structures will lead to extra-grammatical analyses (ie 'the rules' will be broken).

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot. I got it. But then what are the rules for elliptical structure? I mean with the help of your explanation, I understand this case. But for other cases, when I am going to write on my own? Please I need some help.

Comment: I'm sorry, (and I'm off to watch the cricket :-) ), but there are no easy ways. You have to (a) recognise that there are only 'rules of thumb', guidelines, in English and (b) look up or ask about (when you come across) unusual (to the learner) bits of grammar. You might look up 'extragrammatical idioms' or 'ungrammatical idioms' for a few examples – most of these have probably arisen because of ellipsis.

Comment: @Man_From_India The bowling was too good. Look up all the discussions on ellipsis (the omission of words from structures as opposed to the punctuation mark ...) here for starters.

Comment: Can you provide me with some link?

Comment: Just search under 'ellipsis' and ignore the ones that mean the punctuation mark (...). There's also 'be-deletion', 'whiz-deletion' 'conjunction reduction' and 'conversational deletion'. (Try searches with and without double inverted commas.) [John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93945/what-do-you-call-a-past-participlenoun-construction-clause-such-as-no-offense/93947#93947) provides excellent treatments and links.

Comment: Ah but the reductio you've correctly identified needs the second assumption to be rejected: "*A noun is the only part of speech possible after a preposition*". This assumption is clearly **out of** order!

Comment: That's not accepted by all. Certainly 'out of' here (opposite of 'in' in this usage) is often called **a** preposition (a multi-word or compound one, of course). The analysis (analyses) of what appear to be multi-preposition constructions in English is/are far from easy. Here is a link to an [abstract from an article by Evelien Keizer](http://home.hum.uva.nl/fg/abstr_icfg13/Keizer.html); I think the whole article is still available.

Answer (score 13):

## *To prate or not to prate? That is the scortle.*

You’ve asked a loaded question when you say, “Can an adverb be noun?”  It has hidden assumptions that render both potential answers — that is, either *yes* or *no* — in some way wrong.

It’s like asking someone whether they’ve stopped beating their husband yet.  No matter whether they answer *yes* or *no*, they’ve landed themselves in hot water.

In the husband-beating question, the problems should I hope be self-evident.  In yours, let me spell them out for you.

You are assuming that a word in isolation “is” some part of speech. This is never true.  Parts of speech and other, broader labels (such as *subject, predicate, verbal phrase, adverbial phrase, direct object,* &c)  are applied to [constituents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) of a  phrase or larger utterance once it has been subjected to syntactic analysis — once it has been parsed.

A single word in complete isolation has no part of speech. It cannot. Only when you deduce or infer what role that word is playing in the larger syntactic context can one begin to assign such labels.

For example, what part of speech is each of these words:

- floop
- flump
- plock
- prate
- rast
- ruzz
- ruzzle
- rynt
- scortle
- tyrn

Kinda tough, right?  Would these additions make it any easier?

- derasted
- flooped
- floopess
- floops
- flumper
- flumpette’s
- nyrt’s
- plockest
- prated
- pratess
- pratest
- rastest
- rastfully
- ruzzest
- ruzzled
- scortle’s

The answer is yes, it helps considerably — but not completely.  That’s because what you really need to complete the job is this:

> My scortle’s floopess prated me to rastfully flump her the ruzzest plock I could tyrn.

Or perhaps this:

> My nyrt’s pratess flooped me to ruzz her the plockest flumper I could scortle the rastest.

Or maybe even this:

> My flumpette’s scortle ruzzled me to pratefully plock her the most derasted of floops I could rynt.

I trust you will now have no trouble assigning parts of speech to all of *floop, floops, flooped, floopess, flump, flumper, flumpette’s, nyrt’s, plock,
plockest, prated, pratess, pratest, ruzz, ruzzest, ruzzled, rynt, scortle,
scortle’s,* and *tyrn*.

## *The flumpette’s rast floop*

Or will you?

You see, without having the sentences, you can have no part of speech.  And even once you have the sentences, the part-of-speech tag assigned a lexical item in one sentence quite often contradicts the POS assignment in another sentence.

So you see, it makes no sense to ask whether an adverb can be noun. It cannot be, because it is an adverb.  That does not mean that a word that is sometimes used as an adverb cannot turn around the next floop and get itself used as noun this time around.

A good example of that is *today*, *tomorrow*, and *yesterday*. Today I have nothing to do, but tomorrow I shall rue the yesterday that I shall by then have squandered.  Or, as a better writer than I once said:

> *She should have died hereafter.
>
>   There would have been a time for such a word.
>
>   **Tomorrow, and tomorrow, and tomorrow**,
>
>   Creeps in this petty pace from day to day
>
>   To the last syllable of recorded time,
>
>   And **all our yesterdays** have lighted fools
>
>   The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle!
>
>   Life’s but a walking shadow, a poor player
>
>   That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
>
>   And then is heard no more. It is a tale
>
>   Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury,
>
>   Signifying nothing.*

So whether you classify a word as this or that, it signifies nothing in isolation.

## *Partes orationis quot sunt?*

This is true for Donatus’s eight classical parts of speech, from

> [Partes orationis quot sunt? Octo. Quae?](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/donatus.4.html)
>
> - nomen
> - pronomen
> - verbum
> - adverbium
> - participium
> - coniunctio
> - praepositio
> - interiectio

To the modern analyst’s standard workhorses:

- articles
- quantifiers
- determiners
- adjectives
- numbers
- nouns
- pronouns
- clitics
- verbs
- proverbs
- adverbs
- circumpositions
- conjunctions
- contractions
- expletives
- interjections
- negators
- particles
- prepositions
- postpositions

To the subdivider’s nuanced list of:

- demonstrative adjectives
- zero article
- definite articles
- indefinite articles
- partitive articles
- correlative conjunctions
- coördinating conjunctions
- subordinating conjunctions
- count nouns
- mass nouns
- proper nouns
- cardinal numbers
- direction particles
- locative particles
- demonstrative pronouns
- demonstrative pronouns
- emphatic pronouns
- impersonal pronouns
- indefinite pronouns
- interrogative pronouns
- locative pronouns
- personal pronouns
- possessive pronouns
- reciprocal pronouns
- reflexive pronouns
- relative pronouns
- possessive terminers
- auxiliary verbs
- bitransitive verbs
- copular verbs
- intransitive verbs
- modal verbs
- transitive verbs

Because no matter what set you pick — and there are many others besides just these three — when you try to talk about them in the abstract and apply them to a single word in isolation, they are all so much sound and fury, signifying nothing.

## *The plocking flumper*

In closing, kindly let me commend to you these two scortling answers for unruzzled meditations:

- [What exactly is an “adverb”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510)
- [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874)

Comment: +1 and I am sorry to hear about your scortle’s floopess. I have to say never really trusted her.

Comment: This answer already has a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69191/english-parts-of-speech-better-new-treatments).

Answer (score 7):

> *The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile than ever before.*

As usual with confusing sentences, this one has been done things to.

First, the final /n/ in *than* has been misheard at some link in the chain and added to *ever*.
Producing the ungrammatical phrase *than never before*. That's corrected to *ever* above.

Second, big chunks of the sentence have been sheared off by several deletion rules; 
this is normal for a comparative construction, where the machinery of comparison is mostly 
taken for granted.

Third, and most important, comparative constructions are **really** complicated. For example,
a stripped-down version of what the comparative construction produces might be

- *The new `T` resembles `F`

  **more than***
  *the (previous) `T` has **ever** resembled `F` **before**.*

Since the subject *`T`* and the predicate *resemble `F`* are mentioned in the first clause,
they get deleted by optional [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), leaving only the boldface pieces, both adverbs.

So what we have here in the original sentence is the remains of a deceased clause,
with the repeated parts left out because they're predictable.

And that's why *than* looks like a preposition. But it's not -- it's part of the comparative construction.
If you absolutely have to give *than* a name, then call it the English Comparative Conjunction. *Than* is never used outside 
of comparative constructions of one kind or another.

As for the rest, *before* is an adverb, and the reason you think it "acts like a noun after *than*"
is because you think *than* is a preposition, with an object noun. Since it's not a preposition,
all bets are off. Actually, it's a subordinate clause, part of the comparative construction,
but *ever before* is the only part of that clause that's left standing.

Oh, one final point. Dictionaries do not give all -- or often any -- of the grammar for words. Grammar can't be looked up in a dictionary; particularly English grammar, which is all syntax -- i.e, it's words in constructions, not words by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *ever* instead of *never* although I doubt it changes the meaning at all:

> The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile than ever before.

I actually read that sentence as:

> The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile than [it] ever [was] before.

Or in a simpler sentence:

> I have more money now than ever before.
>   I have more money now than [I] ever [had] before.

The same goes for:

> I feel better today than yesterday.
>   I feel better today than [I felt] yesterday.

Why should *ever before* or *yesterday* be acting as a noun?

Comment: Exactly how "ever before" acting as noun?

Comment: Who says it is acting as a noun? Can you explain why you think it is acting as a noun?

Comment: See in "on a table", "on" is a preposition, and "a table" is a noun. In case of "than before", "than" is a preposition, and "before" is an adverb. How is it possible?

Comment: @Man_From_India So you're saying that prepositions must always be followed by a noun. This answer demonstrates that's not so.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Actually I have no idea, I thought it is the case. Can you please make me correct?

Comment: Your own sentence is an example. _than_ is not followed by a noun. Your question _why_ it is followed by a noun is therefore invalid

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary *does* have a listing for "before" as a noun, meaning "in front of" or "an earlier period of time" (with the example of "from before", which doesn't yield to the ellipsis theory as well as "than before"). So the answer is, yes, it can be a noun. But it's not because an adverb can be a noun; it's because "before" can be an adverb or a noun (or a preposition or a conjunction) depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile than ever before
or
The new design of Twitter profile is more of a Facebook profile, never before had it been so similar.

Comment: But me no buts. But but is usually not a verb or a noun.